# com.googlProvider com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalCloudDatastoreV1Service could not be instantiated

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-gradle-plugin

I'm completely new in android and Google App Engine staff. I want to run a `JUnit` test on one of my class methods. But I have received an exception which I have tried to google for `solns` but all in vain.

I am using android studio 1.3 on ubuntu Ubuntu 15.04 64bit.

Here's the error that am getting from my android studio console

> java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.google.appengine.tools.development.
>       LocalRpcService: Provider com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.
>       LocalCloudDatastoreV1Service could not be instantiated
>
> at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.startServices(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:600)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.access$700(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:46)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$2.run(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:584)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$2.run(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:581)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.getService(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:580)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.callInternal(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:496)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:475)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:452)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable$1.run(Executors.java:533)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable.call(Executors.java:530)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

What should I do to solve the problem?

**UPDATE**

Here is my LocalServiceTestHelper declaration.

```
public class MyClassTest {

  static {
    ObjectifyService.register(AccountUser.class); 
  }

  LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    helper.setUp();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    helper.tearDown();
  }

  @Test
  public void myClassMethodUnderTest() throws Exception {
    //method codes are here e.g
    AccountUser user1 = new AccountUser();
    user1.setFirstName("Daniel");
    user1.setLastName("Toroitich-Arap-Moi");
    user1.setEmail("Moi@Gmail.com");
    user1.setId(new Long(1));

    ofy().save().entity(user1).now();
  }
}
```

Comment: YOU GUYS, I REALLY NEED YOUR HELP. I HAVE STRUGGLED WITH THIS FOR WEEKS!!!.

Comment: Which version of GAE are you using?

Comment: @Aakash        this is from my module's build.gradle file **appengineSdk com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.24**

Comment: Can you verify if your sdk, appengine-testing and appengine-api-stubs are all having the same version? If not make sure they do have the same versions.

Comment: @Aakash        They are all having the same version                                                                                                          **testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:1.9.24'**
    **testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:1.9.24'**
    **testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:1.9.24'**
    **testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.24'**
   **testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-tools-sdk:1.9.24'**

Comment: Provide your LocalServiceTestHelper declaration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89769/discussion-between-aakash-and-gikarasojo-kinene).

Comment: @Aakash i have updated my question and provided my LocalServiceTestHelper initialization. please have a look at it